# IIS server access issue over WWW

Tags: iis, firewall

I have installed IIS server on Windows 7 professional.
I am able to access the server using IP  lets say   172.8.5.1   but when I try to ping the site outside of company network I get a network error (tcp_error)

Any one knows what needs to happen in order to access it over WWW?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a static IP adresse,and then authorize incoming http request on port 80 from your router or your firewall.But the ip adresse should be accessible by internet

Comment: It is on company intranet and I have authorized inbound connections to port 80